# Are there APIs or other methods to communicate with Mac OS X and iOS(iPhone and iPad)?

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth

I want to know whether there are APIs or other methods to communicate with Mac OS X and iOS. I have googled the problem and found no results. Moreover, someone said there is no official support for it. Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: To communicate from where with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just about any network protocol from Bonjour to ZMODEM to communicate between an iOS device and a Mac. HTTP is, of course, one very popular choice. As a bonus, most options work equally well to talk to devices running Windows and unix-y operating systems.